# AngularJS: Current tab lost focus (background color) after I clicked somewhere else

Tags: css, angularjs

I have 2 tabs:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-disabled="isLoading">    
<!--Tab Menu Start -->    
<tabset>        
    <tab heading="Accounts" href="#portlet_tab1" data-toggle="tab"> </tab>        
    <tab heading="Payment" href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab"> </tab>        
</tabset>    
</div>
```

The page's background color is white. When I click `Accounts`, the tab is focused, with a text background color change to FF0000. Same rule applies to the `Payment` tab as well. However when I click somewhere else, let's say a blank space in the page, the background color underneath `Accounts` is gone. It turns white again. How to make the current tab to be able to maintain the unique backgroud color of FF0000?

Comment: Could you try to expand the code a wee bit into a [mcve]?

Comment: The active tab has `active` class on it, so apply the style to `.nav-tabs>li.active>a {background: #FF0000;}`

Comment: @AlonEitan I see that class already existing in css but those are `<tab>` not `<li>`

Comment: @DylanChensky Perhaps on newer version of bootstrap-ui they changed it to `LI` - Inspect the active tab [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) and you'll see that it transform into `LI`